# How to make arrow avoid/go around text?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My arrow comes out at the right angle of the '3', but it almost immediately goes over some other text? I added a node at the 's' in 'simple' but not sure how to make the line avoid the node via the bottom left of it. Is that possible? Similar situation for the 'n' in 'nominal' on the right column.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
%\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows,shapes]
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{1 \linewidth}\centering
        \begin{tabular}{  L{5cm}  C{1cm}  L{5cm}   } 
            \hspace{7pt}\hspace{2cm}Outstanding\newline\hspace{7pt}\hspace{2cm}balance at\newline\hspace{7pt}\hspace{2cm}the end of\newline\hspace{7pt}\hspace{2cm}\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(n1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node[] (n1) {3}; years at\newline\hspace{7pt}\hspace{2cm}\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(j.base),inner sep=0pt] \node[] (j) {s};imple rate \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(n2.base),inner sep=0pt] \node[] (n2) {$r$}; & = & Outstanding\newline balance at\newline the end of\newline\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(n3.base),inner sep=0pt] \node[] (n3) {3}; years at\newline nominal rate $j_{365}=8\%$ \\ 
            \hspace{20pt}\hspace{2cm}$P\left(1+\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(n4.base),inner sep=0pt] \node[anchor=north] (n4) {$r$};\cdot\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(n5.base),inner sep=0pt] \node[anchor=south west] (n5) {3};\right)$ & = & \hspace{-11pt}$P\left(1+\frac{j_{365}}{365}\right)^{365\cdot \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(n6.base),inner sep=0pt] \node[] (n6) {\scriptsize3};}$ \\ 
            So\hspace{23pt}\hspace{2cm}$1+3r$ & = & $\left(1+\frac{8\%}{365}\right)^{365\cdot3}$  \\
            Thus,\hspace{26pt}\hspace{2cm}$3r$ & = & $\left(1+\frac{0.08}{365}\right)^{365\cdot3}-1$\\
            Hence, \hspace{79pt}$r$& = & $\frac{1}{3}\left[\left(1+\frac{0.08}{365}\right)^{365\cdot3}-1\right]$\\
            & $\cong$ & 0.0904\\
            & = & 9.04\%
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[->] (n1) to [out=225, in=145,looseness=1.5] node[] {} (n5); % Here we connect the nodes
\draw[->] (n2) to [out=285, in=85,looseness=1] node[] {} (n4); % Here we connect the nodes
\draw[->] (n3) to [out=225, in=90,looseness=1] node[] {} (n6); % Here we connect the nodes
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you complete your example so we can compile it?

Comment: Fixed. The MWE got messed up during my last edit. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cheap solution in your case is to tweak the exit and entry angles, and to add a looseness parameter:

```
\draw[->] (n1) to [out=225, in=145, looseness=1.5] node[] {} (n5);
```

In the more general case, you can specify additional control points. See for example the question:  [tikz - specifying more controls on curved lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99999/tikz-specifying-more-controls-on-curved-lines)

edit: for more accurate control, try bezier control points:

```
\draw[->] (n1) .. controls ++(220:2) and ++(120:1) .. (n5);
\draw[->,blue] (n3) .. controls ++(225:2) and ++(105:1.35) .. (n6);
```

The two control points are specified in polar coordinates relative to the points of origin and of arrival, respectively. Play around with the angles and the radii to get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It worked for the first arrow, but in my original post I hadn't included the other two arrows necessary for this diagram. For the third arrow your suggestion doesn't seem to be able to be tweaked to work. The OP has been updated.

Comment: Adding the control specifics allowed me to tweak each just right! Thanks for your help! Much appreciated!